# Switching views when sending email infopath

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have a form with two views, the user view and approver view. The approver view is an exentension of the user view. How do I have a email sent from the user view but have the approver view show in the email, with all the relevant fields that have been filled out by the user showing ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what approaches you've tried, but its logical to go the **Perform custom action using Rules** route, having 2 rules...one to switch the view and one to send the email.  Unfortunately this doesn't work...jury's been out on whether this is a bug or by design for a long time.

The standard approach to accomplish this is 2 sections in a single view and using rules to show and hide the sections as needed.

Here is a post from the InfoPath team on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/01/17/emailing-a-custom-view.aspx

It's targeted for 2007, but will work with 2010 as well.

Hope this helps.